# reload UIPickerView that is in UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uipickerview

I have created an UIPickerView in the UIAlertView using this code:

```
alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200)];
alert1.title = @"All Notes";
alert1.message = @"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
alert1.delegate = self;
[alert1 addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

 myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
 myPickerView.tag = TAG_PICKER0;
 myPickerView.delegate = self;
 myPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
 myPickerView.autoresizingMask = UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
 myPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 40, 265, 150);

 [alert1 addSubview:myPickerView];
 [alert1 show];
```

I want to reload this pickerView when pressing a button, in button action I added a new element to the array that appears in the picker and I also added this line

```
[self.myPickerView reloadAllComponents];
self.myPickerView.delegate=self;
```

but the new element doesn't appear in the picker at this moment, it appears when I reopen the application

how can I solve this issue to make the new element appears in the pickerView at the moment of adding ??

Comment: Did you try to do self.myPickerView.delegate=self; BEFORE [self.myPickerView reloadAllComponents]; ?

Comment: Where in the app are the code snippets that you posted? Is the button method in the class that is your picker's data source and delegate?

Comment: Also, why are you resetting the delegate after the reloadingAllComponents line?  Is that "self" different from the "self" where you first set the delegate?

Comment: I tried to put self.myPickerView.delegate=self; BEFORE [self.myPickerView reloadAllComponents]; but no result :(, I putted the code of picker in a button action and the code of reload is in other button action.

Comment: Are both those button actions in the same class?  And I'll ask again, why are you resetting the delegate of your picker?  Is that a different delegate than the one where you first set the delegate?